# Cannot get EJB from MBean in JBoss7

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jmx

The problem is following. I am trying to migrate the project from JBoss 4.2 to JBoss 7.1.
Previously ejb lookup was done in following way:

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.security.jndi.JndiLoginInitialContextFactory");
    props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, new SimplePrincipal(login));
    props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(props);
    SomeClass someClass = (SomeClass) ctx.lookup("appName/SomeClass/local");
```

And everything worked fine. Now implementation is following:

```
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
SomeClass someClass = (SomeClass) ctx.lookup("java:app/jarModuleName/SomeClass!com.example.SomeClass");
```

ejb interface:

```
@Local
public interface SomeClass(){
...
}
```

ejb class:

```
@Stateless(name = "SomeClass")
public class SomeClassImpl implements SomeClass() {
...
}
```

During boot jboss shows that binding is:

```
java:app/jarModuleName/SomeClass!com.example.SomeClass
```

But lookup() after causes NameNotFoundException.

The package structure is following:

```
appName.ear
|
+--jmx-services.sar (where lookup method is invoked)
|
+--jarModuleName.jar (where ejb is located.)
```

The content of ejb-jar.xml in jarModuleName:

```
<ejb-jar version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd">
    <session>
        <ejb-name>SomeClass</ejb-name>
        <ejb-class>com.example.SomeClassImpl</ejb-class>
    </session>
</enterprise-beans>
```

Also can specify, that MBeans are created in "old-style", using jboss-service.xml and start()/stop() methods, not @Startup and @Singleton annotation.

Comment: Are client & EJB on same machine? If not I think you need to use remoting as url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use both `@Local` and `@Remote` with two separate interfaces, and I highly recommend using `@EJB`.

Also put your EJBs in different jar file and deploy it.

This folder structure is working for me:

yourApp.ear
{
  -lib
  -META-INF
   {
   application.xml
  }
  -yourEJB.jar
  -yourWebContent.war
}

you should have an application.xml in your META-INF folder, an example of it is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application version="5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd">
  <module>
    <ejb>
      yourEJB.jar
    </ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>
        yourWar.war
      </web-uri>
      <context-root>
        yourAppRoot (use it as localhost://yourAppRoot)
      </context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

deploy yourApp.ear in JBoss.

I haven't use ejb-jar.xml in my apps.

Comment: When using @EJB on field, it throws NPE afterwards, so it is not injected there...

Comment: did you configure the application.xml file for EJB module?

Comment: No, I have ejb-jar.xml for ejb configuration. I will update the question with its content now.

Comment: I think ejb-jar.xml is for just war deployment and applcation.xml is for ear deployment.

Comment: No, I don't have any... I use maven-ear-plugin 2.8 version for ear creation.

Comment: No problem with maven, just create application.xml in META-INF.